# How to access Spring configuration properties in Java class

Tags: mule

If I have my own transformer and I'm doing work in a Java class, how can I access the Spring configuration properties?

In the flow XML I would type something like ${activemq_server}, but in Java I'm not sure how to get that value.

I'm digging through the MuleMessage and all the objects that come with it (Context, Configuration, etc.), but I haven't found them yet.

In the past I've injected them into message properties, but that feels so sloppy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO injecting properties in Spring beans is probably the cleanest.

Alternatively, you can use `util:properties` to load the properties file in a bean and then have the `context:property-placeholder` use this bean for placeholder resolution. This gives you the possibility to either inject or use MEL to lookup this bean (like `#[app.registry.myProperties.propertyName]`.

Comment: Injecting with Spring beans worked perfectly. Chalk it up to my ignorance of Spring beans.

Comment: So is there no way of accessing properties defined through context:property-placeholder.